# Build single SQL table from multiple single columns of R data

Tags: r, postgresql, bigdata

I am working with a very large biological dataset, with ~1000 variables (a mixture of numeric and character) measured from ~1,000,000 cells. Needless to say, the table is too large to fit into memory. Dropping variables isn't an option for my downstream analysis, and the table is likely to grow over time. My strategy is therefore to convert the data into an SQL database that can easily be queried from R.

Here I am using a PostgreSQL database with the DBI and ODBC packages:

```
db <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                 Driver = "PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(UNICODE)",
                 Server = "127.0.0.1",
                 Database = "db1",
                 UID = "user",
                 PWD = "password")
```

For a small table in memory, a new table `data` can be created thus:

```
dbWriteTable(db, "data", data)
```

Similarly, for a large table on disk (such as a big .csv) one could process the data in batches. i.e. Load 100 rows of the data at a time, and append the rows to grow the SQL table.

However, in my case this strategy is not possible as each variable (column) is stored as a vector in a separate file on disk (it's from a proprietary format, nothing I can do to help that). Therefore, to build the SQL table I would need to load each column into R, and then add each column in turn to the SQL database.

What is the best way to build up the table one column at a time? Or is there an alternative strategy I am missing?

For example, would it be possible to create each column as a separate table and then bind them together. e.g.:

```
data = list(col1 = 1:10, col2 = 11:20, col3 = 21:30)

# Create tables
for(i in 1:length(data)) {
   dbWriteTable(db, as.character(i), data.frame(col1))
}

### Function to bind columns into single table ###
```

Comment: Do you have a unique identifier for each virtual "row" of data that is shared across your vector data?

Comment: `UPSERT`ing it certainly a thing, though its performance will not be good in the long haul. I think it would be better to incrementally load vectors from each of these proprietary files (e.g., load the first 100 of each, then write to the table ... load the next 100 from each, then write to the table ... perhaps 100 is not the best number, go as large as you can afford to go with RAM).

Comment: In that thought ... just as the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) chapter 2 (*Growing Objects*) discourages, iteratively building a `data.frame` (either row-wise or column-wise) will bloom memory usage (it copies the frame with each addition).  I suggest: (1) find or write a function that reads a subset of the contents of one file, e.g., `skip=` and `max=` args; (2) find all files and add to a vector, `filenames`; (3) capture all data with `dat <- lapply(filenames, myreadfile, skip=0, max=100)`; then (4) `as.data.frame(dat)` then upload.

Comment: @PhilipWrage. There is not a unique identifier for each row, however each vector is in the same order and has the same number of rows (so in R a simple cbind would keep them together). An extra column `1:length(col1)` could be added to each iteration if necessary.

Comment: @r2evans. Loading each column into a list and then running `data.frame(list)` does not copy the data as far as I know, and is pretty much instant regardless of the size of the data.

Comment: @DGreenwood that's what I was leaning towards. Copying happens when you start with `dat <- data.frame(...); dat$newcol <- ...; dat$newcol2 <- ...;`, which is the iterative growth I was discouraging. (This can be witnessed by running `tracemem(dat)` after the first call and watching it reassigned on each update.)

Comment: @DGreenwood, without a unique identifier or index for each row, then I don't know how you can insert one column *safely* at a time via SQL. (I always assume any operation in SQL is *unordered*, so I've never tested inserting arbitrary data and assuming the order is preserved between inserts. Ergo the thought for having a unique id. I dislike have database tables without some way of guaranteeing unique access to each row, even if I never use it in day-to-day activity. I suggest either an auto-incrementing INT or a GUID/UUID, postgres supports both.)

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. I'm not familiar with the implementation of SQL databases, so thank you for pointing out that operations are not necessarily linearly ordered.

Comment: Yup. (1) Think about this: looking at an Excel table, without the 1,2,3 row labels, how do you replace a column value for a particular row? Are the rest of the values on that row so perfectly unique among all rows that you can rely perfectly on that? (That's a little cumbersome, too.) (2) Row order: realize that databases want to store things *efficiently*, and that may be in the order they are inserted, or alphabet order, or ordered to maximize spread on a drive platter (idk). Either way, you cannot assume order when you insert, and on `select` only if you include `order by` in the query.